# Multiple Global Key

Tags: flutter, dart, key

I am new in Flutter and I need help for dummies. Because every time I move my ReorderableList, my terminal sends me a message "Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey."

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:todoapp2/models/global.dart';
import 'package:todoapp2/models/widgets/intray_todo_widget.dart';
import 'package:todoapp2/models/classes/task.dart';

class IntrayPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IntrayPageState createState() => _IntrayPageState();
}

class _IntrayPageState extends State<IntrayPage> {
  List<Task> taskList = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    taskList = getList();
    return Container(
      color: darkGreyColor,
      child: _buildReorderableListSimple(context),
      // child: ReorderableListView(
      //   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
      //   children: todoItems,
      //   onReorder: _onReorder,
      // ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListTile(BuildContext context, Task item) {
    return ListTile(
      key: Key(item.taskId),
      title: IntrayTodo(
        title: item.title, keyValue: '',
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildReorderableListSimple(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
          canvasColor: Colors.transparent
      ),
      child: ReorderableListView(
        // handleSide: ReorderableListSimpleSide.Right,
        // handleIcon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200.0),
        children: taskList.map((Task item) => _buildListTile(context, item)).toList(),
        onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
          setState(() {
            Task item = taskList[oldIndex];
            taskList.remove(item);
            taskList.insert(newIndex, item);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    setState(() {
      if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
        newIndex -= 1;
      }
      final Task item = taskList.removeAt(oldIndex);
      taskList.insert(newIndex, item);
    });
  }

  List<Task> getList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      taskList.add(Task("My first todo " + i.toString(), false, i.toString()));
    }
    return taskList;
  }

}
```

And now my second File

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../global.dart';


class IntrayTodo extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String keyValue;
  IntrayTodo({required this.keyValue, required this.title});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      key: Key(keyValue),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      height: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        boxShadow: [
          new BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
            blurRadius: 10.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
         /* Radio(

          ),*/
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(title, style: darkTodoTitle,)
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

[An image what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyCRj.png)

My "App" is working, (buggy because of the key problem) its a simple ToDo App, because I am trying to learn and trying to keep my brain fit. I don't know how to solve this problem. I googled very much but  didn't get it so that is my last option to ask you in hope someone can help. Where should I put the key? I read somewhere "in the method" but I didn't get it.

Error Code:

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2653:12)
#3      RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2675:61)
#4      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3331:14)
#5      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.visitChildrenForSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:398:11)
#6      RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2670:5)
#7      RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2675:61)
#8      RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3048:14)
#9      RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2760:5)
#10     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2670:5)
#11     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2675:61)
#12     Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:257:30)
#13     RenderViewportBase.visitChildrenForSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:222:10)
#14     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2670:5)
#15     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2675:61)
#16     RenderIgnorePointer.visitChildrenForSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3266:14)
#17     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2670:5)
#18     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2675:61)
#19     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3048:14)
#20     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2760:5)
#21     RenderSemanticsAnnotations.visitChildrenForSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:4663:11)
#22     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2670:5)
#23     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2675:61)
#24     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3048:14)
#25     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2760:5)
#26     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2670:5)
#27     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2675:61)
#28     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3048:14)
#29     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2760:5)
#30     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2670:5)
#31     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2675:61)
#32     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3048:14)
#33     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2760:5)
#34     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2670:5)
#35     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2675:61)
#36     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3048:14)
#37     RenderObject.visitChildrenForSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2760:5)
#38     RenderObject._getSemanticsForParent
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2670:5)
#39     RenderObject._updateSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2631:41)
#40     PipelineOwner.flushSemantics
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1076:16)
#41     RendererBinding.drawFrame
(package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:467:21)
#42     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
(package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:876:13)
#43     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:328:5)
#44     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#45     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#46     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:998:5)
#50     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:163:10)
#51     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:259:5)
#52     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:126:31)
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)

Another exception was thrown: Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys in flutter are meant to be unique.
But in your example code the same key with the same value is used when the widget rebuilds.

What happens is that when you create a key, flutter stores it (Not as scoped variable which is deleted when the function is done) and when the widget is rebuilt, flutter tries to create a new key with the same value and it finds that there's an old key with the same value which result to that error

It's better if you defined your keys outside the build function.
like

```
final Key _key = Key('unique_key');

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  .
  .
  .
```

Edit: As it mentioned here [ReordarableLitView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html)
You can refactor your code to look like that
in `IntrayPage` change the children of the list to look like

```
children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < taskList.length; index++)
          _buildListTile(context, taskList[index], index) 
      ],
```

Change the _buildListTile to receive the index and send it to the `IntrayTodo` widget

```
Widget _buildListTile(BuildContext context, Task item, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      key: Key(item.taskId),
      title: IntrayTodo(
        title: item.title, keyValue: '$index',
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I don't know how to implement  your code, if I try to do Key on the top of this Widget and delete the other keys, there is an huge error as before. Its not your code, it's because I don't know how to do it right. Can you help me a little bit more if u have time? This key problem ist really hard for me...

Comment: I just don't understand why you even need keys. the app would work fine without any keys

Comment: Its a ToDo App and I wanted to do an Reorderable List where I can drag and drop the container with a "task" and I read somewhere that they did it with keys. If u have a better way to do it just tell me and I will try to do it :D Its my very first project.

Comment: ```Another exception was thrown: All children of this widget must have a key.

``` Thats the error when I remove the keys

Comment: If I scroll down, after the fifth task, its calling me the same error. Its still working but it is buggy, the app doesn't crash and I can see the display but if I drag one task from the bot to the top or scroll down at this moment I see the same error. Thank you for your help really. I think I am too bad I don't know. Its "only" a list god damn